# Installed product is not listed in quickinstaller

Tags: plone

I am trying to import a plone3 data.fs into plone4, but it comes up with this error

```
TypeError: ('object.__new__(RateAgainstBaseRate) is not safe, use Persistence.Persistent.__new__()', <function _reconstructor at 0x7fbe8c0e38c0>, (<class 'currency.converter.currency_data.RateAgainstBaseRate'>, <type 'object'>, None))
```

I thought that removing the product before truing to import the db could solve the problem.
When I search the zmi in plone3 for currency.converter it finds:

Installed Product at  /atf/portal_quickinstaller/currency.converter

Though when I visit the quickinstaller, it is not listed. There is also nothing in the file system.

currency.converter is in the egg section of buildout.cfg but removing it from there and re-running buildout also causes this error in plone3:

```
Error Type: TypeError
Error Value: ('object.__new__(RateAgainstBaseRate) is not safe, use Persistence.Persistent.__new__()', <function _reconstructor at 0x7f55e1fa38c0>, (<class 'currency.converter.currency_data.RateAgainstBaseRate'>, <type 'object'>, None))
```

Any recommendations on how to remove this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to regain control of this product by installing the new 0.55 version.